# androidTestCompile and dependency on another module ends with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm trying to test some code that part of it comes from another module. All the test pass except these which are referencing classes from java module. I've this configuration but it doesn't work:

```
androidTestCompile(project(':common'))
compile project(':common')
```

Exception during runtime:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class...
...
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
```

How to add another module's classes to test apk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with one additional line in `settings.gradle`.  Something was messed up in this file.

```
include ':common'
```

In your `build.gradle` you just need:

```
compile project(':common')
```